# Do there exist publicly available Genome sequences of a family?

Tags: genetics, genomes, database

I would like to explore the genome sequence of a publicly available genome sequences of a family (like mother, father, son, daughter...). If such human genome sequences are not publicly available at least any animal's family data is also OK. :)  I am not a biologist, but aims to just understand things more clearly.

Comment: For animals and other organisms, NCBI has a database for publicly-available sequences:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/guide/howto/retrieve-seq-org/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know that [1000 Genomes](http://www.1000genomes.org/home) has sequenced Mother-Father-Child genomes from populations around the world (I think at least some of these samples were obtained from [HapMap](http://hapmap.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/)) and their data is publicly available by following the links in their website.